# How to import MetaDataAPI to my SalesForce project?

Tags: metadata-api, picklist, metadata, field-update, wsdl2apex

I want to Update Picklist Values in a standard field in my project every X time.

in my Apex Classes I was writing that function:
[image: Apex Metadata Function]

I search for this error and figure out that I need to import MetaDataAPI to my project.
I try a lot of ways to import that API.
From Github, I don't understand exactly how to get all classes to my project. Copy and paste to new files didn't work.
Github-link: [MetaDataAPI GitHub LINK](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes)

another way, I download a WSDL file from Salesforce API documentation and after fix some bugs I stack over this:
[image]

Please Help me!!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue is that you are trying to copy and paste file content into the Setup UI for Apex classes, one class at a time. This would be difficult to do as you must start at the bottom of the class dependency tree and work your way up.

Instead, you need to have all the code (all the relevant Apex class files) on your local file system and use one of the many different ways to deploy it or push it to your org all in one go (so all the dependencies are resolved during that one act of deployment).

You can deploy the classes (and any other required metadata since Apex code is just a specific type of metadata) using:

- An IDE such as [VSCode](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/) or [IntelliJ IDEA and Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/)
- the [SFDX CLI tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm)
- the [Ant migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm) (not recommended)

By far the easiest way to deal with this is using an IDE, though you need to get it installed and configured appropriately. There are [trailheads that help you out with VSCode](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code), for example.